# How can I slow down smooth scrolling speed in React while using scrollIntoView

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, smooth-scrolling

What I need is to slow down the speed of the default smooth scrolling speed in `element.scrollIntoView()`. I have found some solutions that scroll pixel by pixel using `scrollTo`, but the problem is that scrollTo doesn't work if the screen has an overflow-hidden. So I can't find a way to scroll with a specific speed and keep the overflow hidden.

Comment: This is not a feature of react, it's a feature of the browser and you cannot control the speed at which it scrolls as far as I am aware. It's more of a suggestion. If you need this, you can always scroll the box yourself using its `.scrollTop` property and an `animationFrame` (although I bet there are a thousand libraries out there that you could use if that sounds too complicated).

Comment: I've tried to use scroll-react, but it doesn't work with overflow-hidden, I'll try with animationFrame